# ArgumentError: :Bucket must not be blank

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3

I'm currently trying to tidy up a method which displays all items in my S3 bucket, and as I already have the Bucket Address defined in my script I thought it best to reference the method rather than put in the address into my listing method. However, when I do so I receive the error

```
ArgumentError: :bucket must not be blank
```

I feel like I'm missing something obvious, surely I don't have to attach the whole addresss into my params? Attached below is the relevant(?) pieces of code.

```
def bucket_name
    'textract-console-eu-central-xxxxxxxxx'
  end

 def s3_resource
    @s3_resource ||= ::Aws::S3::Resource.new(client: s3_client)
  end
```

the code in question

```
def list_bucket_objects(s3_resource, bucket_name:'')
    puts s3_resource.bucket(bucket_name).objects(prefix:'', delimiter: '').collect(&:key)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You override the `bucket_name` here:

```rb
def list_bucket_objects(s3_resource, bucket_name:'')
                                                 ^
```

Remove the second parameter and you should be good to go.